# Angular Dart: How can we iterate object into html?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have one proto object in angular dart I am taking values from proto object into dart object but I am unable to iterate it into html. How can I achieve this thing into dart like we do in angular?

```
Var obj=[{name:”test”}];
```

Html:

```
{{obj[0][‘name’]}}
```

I have tried to create object like:

```
List<Map<String,String>> details;

    details= [{‘name’:’test’}];
```

Html:

```
{{details[0][‘name’]}}
```

But I am getting error ‘**the getter is not defined for the class**’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code below:

Dart file:

```
 List<Fields> fields = [
    Fields("Jess", 10),
    Fields("Sujuta", 11),
  ];

class Fields {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  const Fields(this.objectName, this.age);
}
```

HTML file:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">{{field.name}}</div>
```